# Unable to deploy an ink! contract with ecdsa_recover

Tags: ink

I have a contract which uses `ink_env::ecdsa_recover()` for signature verification. Though all the tests are passing, I am unable to deploy it on the local node using contracts-ui.

This is the error it's throwing:

```
module imports a non-existent function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What local node are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ink_env::ecdsa_recover()` uses an [unstable interface](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts#unstable-interfaces) of the contracts pallet. Make sure to use the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) which has unstable interfaces enabled by default.